# Copy image and text from clipboard to tinyMCE using javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to copy an image and text from clipboard to tinyMCE.

Is there any solution? or Is it a security limitation?

Answer (score 0):

You can not.
You need put full text and with image url. Or you can integrate plugin upload image to your server site.